# Python 2.5 sub function from regex module not recognizing a pattern

Tags: python, regex, unicode, python-2.5

I'm trying to use Python's sub function from the regex module to recognize and change a pattern in a string.  Below is my code.

```
old_string = "afdëhë:dfp"
newString = re.sub(ur'([aeiouäëöüáéíóúàèìò]|ù:|e:|i:|o:|u:|ä:|ë:|ö:|ü:|á:|é:|í:|ó:|ú:|à:|è:|ì:|ò:|ù:)h([aeiouäëöüáéíóúàèìòù])', ur'\1\2', old_string)
```

So what I'm looking to get after the code is applied is `afdëë:dfp` (without the h).  So I'm trying to match a vowel (sometimes with accents, sometimes with a colon after it) then the h then another vowel (sometimes with accents).  So a few examples...

```
ò:ha becomes ò:a
ä:hà becomes ä:hà
aha becomes aa
üha becomes üa
ëhë becomes ëë
```

So I'm trying to remove the h when it is between two vowels and also remove the h when it follows a volume with a colon after it then another vowel (ie a:ha).  Any help is greatly appreciated.  I've been playing around with this for a while.

Comment: Can you explain how you're matching for the `h`? It's obviously not this simple, so what are you really trying to do? It appears your trying to match a vowel, an accented vowel, or either followed by a semi-colon, followed by an `h`, then followed by a vowel or accented vowel?

Comment: I dont know about 2.5. In python 2.7, the code works fine and it produces `afdëë:dfp`.

Comment: Never name your variables as `string`. There is a builtin module by the same name. Your variable might shadow that module.

Comment: @user2743 Your intent is not clear in the question. What do you exactly want to achieve?

Comment: thanks for the input I edited the questions to help clear things up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A single user-perceived character may consist of multiple Unicode codepoints. Such characters can break `u'[abc]'`-like regex that sees only codepoints in Python. To workaround it, you could use `u'(?:a|b|c)'` regex instead. In addition, don't mix bytes and Unicode strings i.e., `old_string` should be also Unicode.

Applying the last rule fixes your example.

You could write your regex using lookahead/lookbehind assertions:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
from functools import partial

old_string = u"""
  ò:ha becomes ò:a
  ä:hà becomes ä:à
  aha becomes aa
  üha becomes üa
  ëhë becomes ëë"""

# (?<=a|b|c)(:?)h(?=a|b|c)
chars = u"a e i o u ä ë ö ü á é í ó ú à è ì ò".split()
pattern = u"(?<=%(vowels)s)(:?)h(?=%(vowels)s)" % dict(vowels=u"|".join(chars))
remove_h = partial(re.compile(pattern).sub, ur'\1')
# remove 'h' followed and preceded by vowels
print(remove_h(old_string))
```

#### Output

```
  ò:a becomes ò:a
  ä:à becomes ä:à
  aa becomes aa
  üa becomes üa
  ëë becomes ëë
```

For completeness, you could also normalize all Unicode strings in the program using [`unicodedata.normalize()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize) (see the example in the docs, to understand why you might need it).

Answer (score 0):

It is encoding issue. Different combinations of file encoding and old_string being non-unicode behave differently for different pythons.

For example your code works fine for python for 2.6 to 2.7 this way (all data below is cp1252 encoded):

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
old_string = "afdëhë:dfp"
```

but fails with `SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xeb'` if no encoding specified in file.

However, those lines fails for python 2.5 with

```
`UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xeb in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)` for python 2.5
```

While for all pythons fails to remove `h` with old_string being non-unicode:

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
old_string = "afdÃ«hÃ«:dfp"
```

So you have to provide correct encoding **and** define old_unicode being unicode string as well, for example this one will do:

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
old_string = u"afdëhë:dfp"
```